# How to set response body values using data from request using response templating in Wiremock?

Tags: wiremock

I have this JSON definition of request-response. The request body is text/plain.

```
{
  "request": {
    "method": "POST",
    "url": "/users",
    "bodyPatterns": [
      {
        "equalTo": "Name Bob Age 30"
      }
    ]

  },
  "response": {
    "status": 200,
    "body": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><UsersResponse><Name>Bob</Name><Age>30</Age></UsersResponse>",
    "transformers": ["response-template"],
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "text/xml"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to have 'Bob' and '30' not hardcoded but as a variable for both request and response. 
So that if in request 'Mark' '20' arrives I want to return

```
"body": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><UsersResponse><Name>Mark</Name><Age>20</Age></UsersResponse>"
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WireMock and WireMock.Net both support **response templating**:

Documentation:

- [wiremock.org](http://wiremock.org/docs/response-templating/)
- [WireMock.Net](https://github.com/WireMock-Net/WireMock.Net/wiki/Stubbing-and-Request-Matching#response-templating)

However this is limited to simple templating (read the docs for details), it's not possible to define custom code or extract data in a complex way using the JSON mapping interface.

For WireMock.Net you can hard-code this yourself in C#, a different example could look like:

```cs
server.Given(Request.Create().WithPath("/exampleIko"))
    .RespondWith(Response.Create().WithCallback(req =>
    {
        return new ResponseMessage
        {
            Body = "<xml>" + req.Body.Substring(10) +"</xml>"
        };
    }));
```